# Connecting Django to a DB Behind a Proxy

Tags: mysql, django

I'd like to connect a Django to my production MySQL database (read only) so that I can use it to test an analytics application using real data.

Is there a way to specify that django should connect to the db through an ssh proxy in the same way that, say, Sequel Pro lets you specify to connect through a particular SSH proxy with username and password?

If so, what would the `DATABASES` entry look like?

Comment: I think you're better of tunneling through `ssh`. I haven't seen any proxy data in `settings.py`

Comment: Hi Paolo, how can I do that?  Do I create a local mysql instance which is tunneled through to the actual db?  I've seen something like that suggested but didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: First let me get this, you're database is behind a proxy, can't accept incoming connection from outside a local network? If so, what proxy is? Normal firewall? iptables? something that denies outside connections?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use SSH tunneling. To ease your job, you can install `autossh` which automatically checks if the `ssh` connection is alive and re-establishes it if it goes down.

Then you can open a tunnel using the following command:

```
autossh -f -N -L LocalPort:MySQLAddress:MySQLPort your_login@your_server
```

Where:

- `your_server` - the server to which you connect via ssh
- `your_login` - your login on `your_server`
- `LocalPort` - any unused port on the machine where Django is running. This port will be used for the tunnel.
- `MySQLAddress` - the address of your MySQL server as it is reachable from `your_server` (that is, if MySQL is running on `your_server` it will be `127.0.0.1`)
- `MySQLPort` - the port MySQL is listening on

Then in Django settings you specify MySQL IP as `127.0.0.1` and port as the `LocalPort` you set above.

An example:

```
autossh -f -N -L 10000:127.0.0.1:3306 a_user@192.168.1.3
```

When you run this command, you will have an SSH tunnel listening on the local port 10000. So if you connect to localhost:10000, your connection will be tunneled to localhost:3306 on the 192.168.1.3 server.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do the SSH tunnel directly in Python using [sshtunnel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel), and a variant of the following:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.yourserver.com'),
    ssh_username='your SSH server username', ssh_password='secret1',
    remote_bind_address=('your database hostname', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='your database username', password='secret2',
        host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database='your database name, e.g. yourusername$mydatabase',
    )
    # Do stuff
    connection.close()
```

Source: [PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere)